# Long-form arguments aren't passed correctly when using std::process::Command

Tags: linux, rust, command-line-interface

I have an issue where long-form arguments aren't passed correctly to a specific command line utility.

All of this works:

```
Command::new("mpg321").arg("--gain 100").arg("file.mp3").spawn().unwrap()
```

```
Command::new("mpg123").arg("-h 2").arg("file.mp3").spawn().unwrap()
```

```
mpg123 --halfspeed 2 file.mp3
```

But this:

```
Command::new("mpg123").arg("--halfspeed 2").arg("file.mp3").spawn().unwrap()
```

Returns:

```
mpg123: Unknown option "halfspeed 2"
```

I suspect that the fault is on the side of `mpg123`, but that doesn't make complete sense since it works when called from the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mpg123 expects to be called like this: `mpg123 --halfspeed 2 file.mp3`, which makes `argv` look like `{"mpg123", "--halfspeed", "2", "file.mp3"}`. Your way of calling it is equivalent to `mpg123 "--halfspeed 3" file.mp3`, which makes `argv` be `{"mpg123", "--halfspeed 2", "file.mp3"}`, which `mpg123` doesn't understand.

The reason that `"-h 2"` works is that single letter options can be used without a space (meaning you could just write `-h2`), so for those the argument parser needs to be able to handle the case that the option's letter and value are in the same `argv` entry. Apparently that logic is implemented in such a way that it works even if the `argv` entry contains a space.

Comment: Any idea as to why it works with "mpg321" and "--gain 100"?

Comment: @andreyg It doesn't for me ('mpg123: Unknown option "gain 100".') and I'm not sure why it would.

Comment: It's "mpg321", different utility.

Answer (score 4):

`--halfspeed 2` is two arguments. You should call `arg` twice:

```
Command::new("mpg123").arg("--halfspeed").arg("2").arg("file.mp3")...
```

or pass all arguments together as an array using `.args`:

```
Command::new("mpg123").args(&["--halfspeed", "2", "file.mp3"])...
```